# Can a non-TOR client access a TOR web service?

Tags: tor

I really don't know the answer to this. Can a client on the clearnet access a web service being hosted on a server within TOR? Or do both have to be on TOR?

Comment: Going out on a limb here. But maybe [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Absolute answer to your question is no! all the hidden service of TOR is accessible through the TOR network. Access a hidden service is completely different from accessing a web service through INTERNET. It goes through rendezvous and introduction points of the TOR network.

Comment: This is the definitive answer I was expecting. My understanding was that this was the case as well.